# javafx calculate path of a bullet

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to do a Tower Defense and have a little problem with the bullet path, maybe some of you could give me an advice where the problem is.

here i set the gradient for the bullet.

```
bullet.setxGradient((turret.getPosX() - turret.getEnemies().getPosX()));
bullet.setyGradient((turret.getPosY() - turret.getEnemies().getPosY()));
```

here i move the bullets. moveBullet is called in an AnimationTimer.

```
public void moveBullet(Bullet bullet) {

    bullet.setPosX(bullet.getPosX() -  (bullet.getxGradient() ));
    bullet.setPosY(bullet.getPosY() - (bullet.getyGradient() ));
}
```

the problem is, that the bulletspeed is getting slower if the bullet is closer to the turret.
Is there another and maybe a better way to track and set the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer someone gave me and it worked.

```
bullet.setVelocity(new Point2D(turret.getEnemies().getPosX(),turret.getEnemies().getPosY())
.subtract(bullet.getPosX(),bullet.getPosY()).normalize().multiply(3));
```

so i make a Point2D and add the X and Y coordinates of the enemy and the bulletstart.

```
public void moveBullet(Bullet bullet) {
    bullet.setPosX(bullet.getPosX() + bullet.getVelocity().getX());
    bullet.setPosY(bullet.getPosY() + bullet.getVelocity().getY());

}
```

and here i am adding the velocity to the posX and posY.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any timing control in your code. It all depends on how often the AnimationTimer fires and this is not always done at the nominal rate of 60Hz. I'd rewrite the code to compute the bullet position depending on the time past since the bullet was fired.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But the timings wasnt the problem. I just calculated the path wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code is just bits and pieces, helping you is rather impossible. So here is some pseudo code of how it's done:

```
double speed = 1;
double angle = turret.getAngle();

// start at the edge of the turret, not inside of it, given that the turret is centered at location
double x = turret.location.x + Math.cos( angle) * turret.width / 2;
double y = turret.location.y + Math.sin( angle) * turret.height / 2;

// calculate velocity depending on angle
double dx = Math.cos(angle) * speed;
double dy = Math.sin(angle) * speed;

bullet.setLocation( x, y);
bullet.setVelocity( dx, dy);
bullet.setAngle( angle);
```

while your movement in the AnimationTimer is simply

```
location.add(velocity);
```

*Note: angle is in RAD, you probably have to use Math.toDegrees at some point or at least when you rotate the Node*

Looks more or less like this with the big rectangle being a rotating turret which fires rectangular bullets during rotation.

[image]

Comment: This code also does not take into account variations in the AnimationTimers timing. Under heavy load the bullets will become slower.

Comment: The problem of the OP isn't regarding the AnimationTimer, it's that the bullet speed varies depending on the location. Regarding the AnimationTimer, you have to keep it at a stable rate of course.

Comment: mipa could you give me an advise how i should do the loop without an AnimationTimer? would be nice. By the way i am new to programming. Learning by doing.

Comment: @KreCha: You should use an AnimationTimer. Also, this isn't part of the question, you should create a new one if you want an answer to that. Also, you should accept an answer if the question is answered.

Comment: I am not arguing against the use of the AnimationTimer. I just suggest to use  its current time argument to calculate the time difference since the last call in order to react to variations. But Roland is right, that is a new question.